# Use a button to Enable/Disable a text box in VBA

Tags: ms-access, button, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with a text box named Contract_Applying_for which is disabled on form load, but I want to have a button which allows me to edit the contents of the text box.

When I add a button I get presented with the Command Button Wizard, so I have created a Macro called ToggleEnableButton which has the instruction to

```
RunCode Function Name "=ToggleEnableButton()"
```

Then I have written the function

```
Function ToggleEnableButton()

    If Me.Contract_Applying_for.Enabled = True Then
        Me.Contract_Applying_for.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.Contract_Applying_for.Enabled = True
    End If
End Function
```

This seems to produce the error "Member already exists in an object module from which this object module derives."

The code for the ToggleEnableButton_Click is automatically created by the Command Button Wizard and is

```
Private Sub ToggleEnableButton_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_ToggleEnableButton_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "ToggleEnableMacro"
    DoCmd.RunMacro stDocName

Exit_ToggleEnableButton_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_ToggleEnableButton_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ToggleEnableButton_Click

End Sub
```

Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong or a better way to approach this.

Seems like a very simple thing that I am trying to do, but quite a long winded approach.

As suggested by Peekay in the comments I have tried to use a checkbox instead, I wrote

```
Private Sub chbToggleEdit_Click()
If Me.chbToggleEdit.Value = False Then
    Me.Contract_Applying_for.Enabled = False
Else
    Me.Contract_Applying_for.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

This gives the error: "A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communication with the OLE server or ActiveX Control."

Comment: `ToggleEnableButton` its correct but need your entire code to tell whats the problem is

Comment: It may be easier to do this using a checkbox. You need something to store the value of the "Toggle" button. Not sure a command button store a value. A checkbox can.

Comment: I have just tried using a checkbox instead, I'll add the code to my question..

Comment: Thanks for the help, the checkbox code I have written works in an earlier version of my database, so I guess I have done something to corrupt/break the database somewhere along the line so I am going back to the old version which works and am going to work from there... Wish me luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not simply have:

```
Private Sub ToggleEnableButton_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_ToggleEnableButton_Click

ToggleEnableButton()


Exit_ToggleEnableButton_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_ToggleEnableButton_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_ToggleEnableButton_Click

End Sub
```

You can declare your function with the code behind your form.

Let me know if that works,

Ash

Comment: I have tried this, but keep getting "A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communication with the OLE server or ActiveX Control."

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your button rather than the code. Is it possible for you to delete the button and add it in again, without using the wizard?